# Values from a XML file

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the values inside a XML, but with this code I only get the label name value, I want the value itself from the label name.

```
XML Text:
<root><label_params><label_param><name>BranchName</name><value></value></label_param><label_param><name>CustomerCode</name><value></value></label_param><label_param><name>SealNumber</name><value>0110000000420</value></label_param><label_param><name>CustomerName</name><value>PUNTO EDUCATIVO LTDA</value></label_param><label_param><name>LpnTypeCode</name><value>LPN</value></label_param><label_param><name>OutboundNumber</name><value>1685147.1</value></label_param><label_param><name>ReferenceNumber</name><value>18072019_pall_cerr</value></label_param><label_param><name>DeliveryAddress1</name><value>Sin Direccion</value></label_param><label_param><name>NroCita</name><value></value></label_param><label_param><name>FechaEnt</name><value>19/07/2019</value></label_param><label_param><name>Porder</name><value>18072019_pall_cerr</value></label_param><label_param><name>Factura</name><value></value></label_param><label_param><name>IdLpnCode</name><value>C0000000015</value></label_param><label_param><name>TotalBultos</name><value></value></label_param><label_param><name>ANDENWMS</name><value>ANDEN15</value></label_param><label_param><name>LpnPadre</name><value>C0000000015</value></label_param><label_param><name>Cerrados</name><value>4</value></label_param><label_param><name>NoCerrados</name><value>2</value></label_param><label_param><name>TOTALPALLET</name><value></value></label_param></label_params></root>
```

Python Code

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

doc = parse("DataXML.xml")
my_node_list = doc.getElementsByTagName("name")
my_n_node = my_node_list[0]
my_child = my_n_node.firstChild
my_text = my_child.data
print(my_text)
```

Comment: You are specifically selecting tags by name `name`. Do the same for `value` tag. However, traverse the elements from the top in a loop and get all the data you need instead of getting one by one.

Comment: I made this, but didn't worked out.

Instead of name I used the tag: "SealNumber", but didn't return anything.

<name>SealNumber</name><value>0110000000420</value>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

doc = parse("../data/DataXML.xml")
my_node_list = doc.getElementsByTagName("label_param")
for node in my_node_list:
    name_node = node.getElementsByTagName("name")
    value_node = node.getElementsByTagName("value")
    print("Name: "+name_node[0].firstChild.data)
    if(value_node[0].firstChild != None):
        print("Value: "+value_node[0].firstChild.data)
    else:
        print("Value: Empty")
```

Comment: @SebastianFlores as it worked for you, would you please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark?